# Conic sections- parabola

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

My question is: 
Write the equation of the parabola with focus (1,1), whose normal focal chord is parallel to the x-axis
and has length 8. Find its apex, the equation of its directrix and the equation of its axis.

I solved this question and I got two equations of parabolas satisfying the given conditions: 
\begin{align*}
(x-1)^2 = 8 (y+1)
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
(x-1)^2 = -8(y-3).
\end{align*}
Is that true? I want only to make sure that the parabola is not unique.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it seems like the given description isn't enough to uniquely determine a parabola since the description could be satisfied with a parabola opening up or down.